# How does the indexing of GUID keys and int keys in SQL Server work?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, guid, uniqueidentifier

Is that I have been creating a table in SQL that implements GUID, for it I review this question:

[What are the best practices for using a GUID as a primary key, specifically regarding performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specly-rega)

Here an answer tells me to use a GUID key and also another key, but with Identity, so that:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(PKGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
 MyINT INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
 .... add more columns as needed ......)

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PKGUID)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_MyTable ON dbo.MyTable (MyINT)
```

My question is: why use an int key when it says that we are already using the GUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion stems from the multiple meanings of the word "key" in the answer; to wit, the answer states:

> if you want to have your PKGUID column as your primary key (but not
>   your clustering key), and another column MYINT (INT IDENTITY) as your
>   clustering key...

I would change it to say (changes **bolded**):

> if you want to have your PKGUID column as your primary key (but not
>   your **clustered index**), and another column MYINT (INT IDENTITY) as your
>   **clustered index**...

The point is that by default, a PRIMARY KEY is buit on a clustered index (unless you specify otherwise); clustered indexes are then included in every other index, which, in the case of a GUID as a clustered PK, can be a significant performance bottleneck.  The code you posted is a compromise; it satisfies the "need" to have a GUID for a Primary Key, while clustering on a smaller column value (which can lead to a performance boost).

It's not ideal, but it can be a very useful method.  If you'd like to read up more on the differences between keys and indexes, here are some useful links:

[What is the difference between a primary key and a index key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374908/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-index-key)
https://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/difference-between-an-index-and-a-primary-key/
[When should I use primary key or index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878272/when-should-i-use-primary-key-or-index)